Send custom user information using Next-Auth Credentials method with Typescript
I have the usual authOptions file in my [...nextauth] folder and I have been trying to follow the documentations to pass on extra user information using next-auth library. The authentication works fine, but the data I am setting does not go through. The following is the code I've written by following the documentation.
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' }
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) =>  {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error('Invalid Credentials');
        }

        const user = await prisma.staffs.findFirst({
          where: {
            emailId: credentials.email
          },
          include: {
            permissions: true
          }
        });

        // verify credentials and throw errors, and finally return the information 

        return {
          emailId: user.emailId,
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
          admin: user.permissions.admin // this is a boolean
        };
      }
    })
  ],
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.id = account.id
        token.emailId = account.emailId
        token.name = account.name
        token.admin = account.admin
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({session, token}){
      session.user.id = token.id
      session.user.email = token.emailId
      session.user.name = token.name
      session.user.admin = token.admin
      return session;
    }
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
}

VSCode would give type errors without explicitly mentioning the types of User, Session, Account and JWT, so I added the types by going into @types/next-auth.d.ts and added the following code to manage the types:
import { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";
  
declare module 'next-auth' {
    interface User {
        id: string;
        emailId: string;
        name: string;
        admin: boolean;
    }

    interface Session {
        user: {
            id: string;
            emailId: string;
            name: string;
            admin: boolean;
        } & DefaultSession['user'];
    }

    interface Account { 
        name: string;
        id: string;
        emailId: string;
        admin: boolean;
    }
}

declare module 'next-auth/jwt' {
    /** Returned by the `jwt` callback and `getToken`, when using JWT sessions */
    export interface JWT extends Record<string, unknown> {
        name: string;
        id: string;
        emailId: string;
        admin: boolean;
    }
}

However upon adding this, nothing really gets passed over except the name. If I remove all the data-types (i.e. keep the @types/next-auth.d.ts file empty, then I get some errors VSCode Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string' in the session.user.id and similar other names, but all the data gets passed flawlessly. Due to the errors in VSCode I decided to create the types, but upon adding them, no data gets passed through.
If I do not pass the name explicitly, it turns up (which I suspect is due the default interface having name in it), but I could not figure a way to fix this issue.
